# Googly MyBusiness API discovery URL not working

Tags: python, google-my-business-api

I have a Python piece of code that was working with Google MyBusiness API up until several weeks ago (October 2021):

```
discovery_url = 'https://developers.google.com/my-business/samples/mybusiness_google_rest_v4p5.json'

service = build(
    'mybusiness', 
    'v4', 
    credentials=credentials, 
    discoveryServiceUrl=discovery_url
)
```

Now the same piece of code produces the following error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: mybusiness  version: v4
```

Based on their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest), my `discoveryServiceUrl` should be:

```
discovery_url = 'https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest'

service = build(
    'mybusiness', 
    'v4', 
    credentials=credentials, 
    discoveryServiceUrl=discovery_url
)
```

When I make that change, I get another error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4 returned "The request is missing a valid API key.". Details: "The request is missing a valid API key.">
```

I have no idea what API key I should supply in the discovery URL?

Comment: We also got this error from beginning Nov 2021.. Today, we tried with this discovery url and it worked `https://developers.google.com/my-business/samples/mybusiness_google_rest_v4p9.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you are using has been expired. you can use the new APIs like `Account Management API` , `My Business Business Information API`. The documentation link for example for the latter is [My Business Business Information API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest)